# How to disable the button next to Activities in GNOME?

Tags: gnome-shell, top-bar

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 version, there is a GNOME extension that allows you to disable the 'close button' next to "Activities" corner on the left side of top bar. I really dislike to see a button which covers a lot of space and just has a 'close' effect, nothing else.

Do you guys know the extension name? I just can't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The button next to "*Activities*" is called "[App Menu](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/AppMenu)".

App Menu can be designed to contain not just "close" option, but other options related to the corresponding application, e.g. Preferences/Settings, Help, About etc. But almost all the third-party applications (if not all) are not  yet designed to contain any options other than close. If you run native GNOME applications like Files (aka Nautilus), Text Editor (aka Gedit) etc. you'll find there are options other than close.

To remove App Menu from the top-bar you may use *(GNOME) Tweaks*. First install it by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then launch Tweaks, go to "*Top Bar*" section and toggle off the "Application Menu" option.

[image]

Comment: doesn't work on ubuntu 19.10

Comment: doesn't work on ubuntu 20.04